# view have panResponder in scrollview react native

Tags: reactjs, view, scrollview, native

I encountered an issue where I want to use the PanResponder with the following handlers: {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}, but this View is inside a ScrollView. How can I detect the gesture handlers for both the View and the ScrollView?

Thank you everybody!!!

```
   <ScrollView style={{ height: 500 }}>
        <View {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
            ...
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
```